# using class inheritance on tkinter python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, inheritance

please help, I am trying to create a button on a tkinter window with the use of python class inheritance but it does not show the button. I am new to inheritance in python and not sure how do this. please see my code. thanks in advance

```
from tkinter import *

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.mainloop()
class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.my_button = Button(self.root,text="test")
        self.my_button.pack()

d = B()
```

Comment: The code you posted will not produce the error you referring to. Please provide a [mre].

Comment: It is not recommended to call `mainloop()` inside `__init__()`.  For your case, `super().__init__()` inside class `B` will return only after you close the main window, then you try to create button which raises the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not recommended (or should not) call tkinter `mainloop()` inside `__init__()` as `mainloop()` is a blocking function.  Therefore `super().__init__()` will not return until the root window is closed. Since the button is created after `super().__init__()`, so the root window is blank.

Remove `self.root.mainloop()` inside `A.__init__()` and call tkinter `mainloop()` after you created instance of `B()`:

```py
from tkinter import *

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        # don't call mainloop() here

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.my_button = Button(self.root,text="test")
        self.my_button.pack()

d = B()
d.root.mainloop() # call mainloop() here
```